# Embed an iframe in a div, and have div be full height of iframes document

Tags: html, css, iframe, height

I embed an iframe in a div. How can I make that container div be the full height of the iframe's document?

```
<div>
  <iframe width=100% height=100% frameborder=0 src='https://www.graf.ly/dashboards/111?embed=1'></iframe>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3e794/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the parent elements height to `100%` as well...

```
html, body, div.wrap-frame {
    height: 100%;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3e794/1/)</kbd>

---

If you wanna get rid of multiple scroll bars, use

```
iframe {
    display: block;
}
```

Because iframe results in white space at the bottom, hence adds few pixels to 100% which causes multiple vertical scroll...

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/3e794/2/)</kbd>

Just a note, I used a `class` for the wrapper `div` element so that I don't have to use a general element selector / Type Selector.

Also, have an habit of quoting the attribute values.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Alien, this is interesting - I thought height: 100% would set the container div to the height of the containing page's HTML document, not the iframe's height.  Is that not the case?

Comment: @DonnyP When you use `height: 100%;` for any element, it will fail if the parent height is set to auto which is default, and in your case, there was no height for div element, hence 100% of what? and it failed :)

Answer (score 0):

First you will need the iframe to be full document's height. There's a JQuery approach, or you can do it vanilla, but you can't test it on fiddler for iframe domain security issues.

```
var h = $("iframe").contents().find("html").height();
$("iframe").height(h);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div id="content1"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="header.php" ></object>';
</script>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation in your answer as well.